# Optimizing Script Pulling Data From Multiple Google Sheets

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets, iteration

I want a script to search multiple Google Sheets files and pull specific information from each file to create a master status page that my boss can easily see.  The following code works, it's just really slow (and I'm probably not doing it the easiest way).  What's the best way to speed it up? I'm sure there's some way to set up an array, but I'm lost trying to find it.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById()

// Sets up the rules for what to search
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next()
    var filelog = file.getId()
    var tickets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())

//Gets Values from Each File
    var ticketno = tickets.getRange('Form!C1').getValue()
    var jobname = tickets.getRange('Form!C3').getValue()
    var status = tickets.getRange('Form!H1').getValue()
    var assigned = tickets.getRange('Form!C22').getValue()
    var description = tickets.getRange('Form!A18').getValue()


//Sets Values to Master Spreadsheet
    var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Order Status")
    ssh.insertRowAfter(1)
    ss.getRange('Order Status!A2').setValue(ticketno)
    ss.getRange('Order Status!B2').setValue(jobname)
    ss.getRange('Order Status!C2').setValue(status)
    ss.getRange('Order Status!D2').setValue(assigned)
    ss.getRange('Order Status!E2').setValue(description)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looped the scripts 50 times. Runtime of your script was 259,342 seconds, runtime of 'mine' 83,479 seconds

```
function notAsSlow(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1fgROgjHBssvhaSIy5KWv0BhNFlH3EfTI")

  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

  var array=[];

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      var file = files.next()
      var filelog = file.getId()
      var tickets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())

      var dataTickets = tickets.getSheetByName("Form").getDataRange().getValues();

      var ticketno = dataTickets[0][2];
      var jobname = dataTickets[2][2];
      var status = dataTickets[7][0];
      var assigned = dataTickets[21][2];
      var description = dataTickets[17][0];

      array.push([ticketno,jobname,status,assigned,description]);

    }

    var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Order Status");

    if(array[0]){
      ssh.getRange(ssh.getLastRow()+1,1,array.length,5).setValues(array);

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to run this on multiple files, and I couldn't get any of the data to show up. I copied over your code, but maybe there was something to miss?

Comment: @StephenSchonewolf Sorry I did something wrong. In a few minutes I will return with an edited script.

Comment: I went through and load tested it this morning. For really short lists, even with my formatting and sorting additions to the code, it ran in less than 20 seconds.  When I tried with 80 entries it still clocked under a minute and a half. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

**This is faster but really the largest slice in time is probably just opening up the files.**

```
function faster() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById();
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var vA=tss.getSheetByName('Form').getRange(1,1,22,8).getValues();
    var ssh=ss.getSheetByName("Order Status")
    ssh.insertRowAfter(1);//you could avoid this by creating a sheet that you could append to and that would be a little faster
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//not sure if this is needed but this has to complete before the next operation takes place
    ssh.getRange(2,1,1,5).setValues([[vA[0][2],vA[2][2],vA[0][7],vA[21][2],vA[17][0]]]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran the number of files in the folder from the 6 I was testing with up to 48 (about the max I expect to have).  At  6 records, it was 9.75 seconds on yours to 22 seconds on mine.  At 48 Records, it was 2:05.34 on yours to 3:43.44.

Twice as fast is a pretty good improvement.  I think you're right that the hangup is in opening each file.

Comment: You can try removing the SpreadsheetApp.flush().  If it still runs okay  you might get just a little faster.  I don't think there a faster way to do with Google Apps Script.  But possibly @Tanieke or one of the other volunteers will come later and they might know how to use the Sheets API to run it a little faster.  I'm not as familar with the Advanced APIs as some others are.  Accessing I/O is always a bottle neck.

Comment: You might try using Firebase and storing all of the data in a database and then have the master sheet get it all from one source.  That's going to be a lot faster.